# Firebase direct specifc user after login to different activty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is login activity of my project any user login goes to profile activity
i want to make specific user(already have his user and password) goes to different activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    txtEmailLogin =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailLogin);
    txtPwd  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPasswordLogin);
    firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}
public void btnUserLogin_Click(View v){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,"Please Wait","Processing...",true);
    (firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmailLogin.getText().toString(),txtPwd.getText().toString()))
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("Email",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR",task.getException().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: nothing wrong with that code it works fine but every user login goes to same activity and i want to change that for two or three users only that  each one of them go to diiferent activity  and the rest go to profile activty

Comment: Check your condition after the task successfully in a task.isSuccessfi() method and you can redirect the specific user to the specific screen.

Comment: i know that but because i'm beginner i can't write it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change that two or three users to be redirected to diferent activities and the rest to be redirected only to `ProfileActivty`, then you need to change the logic of your code a little bit. So to achieve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

if (uid.equals(firstUserId)) {
    //Redirect this user to FirstActivity
} else if (uid.equals(secondUserId)) {
    //Redirect this user to SecondActivity
} else if (uid.equals(thirdUserId)) {
    //Redirect this user to ThirdActivity
} else {
    //Redirect this user to ProfileActivity
}
```